# Matlab SimBiology - Allow self connecting nodes

Tags: graph, matlab

I'm using Matlab's [SimBiology](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simbio/) tool box to generate [biograph](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/biograph.html) (which are, just graphs).

When I'm trying to include a node which connects to itself, e.g:

```
g = [
       0 1 0;
       1 0 1;
       0 0 1; % This one connects to itself.   
    ]
```

I get the following warning message :

```
Warning: Self connecting nodes are not allowed, ignoring the diagonal of CM.
```

As my data sets include some self connecting nodes, I was wondering if this is a configurable feature.

Thanks!

Comment: +1: Good question. But most algorithms ignore self-loops... I wonder why you need them.

Comment: @Eitan - glad you have asked!  My model is the relations between scientific journals references. The nodes in my graph are scientific journals and the weight of a directed vertex between jourA and jourB are the number of references jourB had to jourA (in - let's say - all articles of the past year). As some articles reference articles that were published in their own journal, I get loops :) This indeed might not be the classic use for biographs...

Comment: As far as I can see, loops are permitted as long as they are not self-loops, because a self-loop means that a vertex points to itself. In your case, this cannot happen because an article cannot reference itself. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately biograph can not have self-connecting edges. If your purpose is only for visualization you could add some nodes with empty labels. Here is an example for a small graph and two self-connecting nodes:

```
cm = [0 1 1 0 0;1 0 0 1 1;1 0 1 0 0;0 0 0 0 1;1 0 1 0 1];
ids = {'M30931','L07625','K03454','M27323','M15390'};

sc = find(diag(cm));
cm = cm-diag(diag(cm)); 
n = size(cm,1);
m = numel(sc);
cm(n+m,n+m)=0;
cm(sub2ind([n+m,n+m],[sc;(1:m)'+n],[(1:m)'+n;sc]))=1;
ids((1:m)+n) = {' '};

bg = biograph(cm);
for i = 1:numel(bg.Nodes)
    bg.Nodes(i).Label = ids{i};
    if i>n
        bg.Nodes(i).Shape = 'circle';
    end
end
view(bg)
```

HTH
Lucio